# Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have the following error since I ran a composer update on my Symfony project. Where can it come from?

I have not changed anything on my dev machine and this is also happening on my staging machine...

```
'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject' not found in 
vendor\zendframework\zend-code\src\Generator\ValueGenerator.php on line 89
```

Here are the list of updated vendors:

```
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle    1.7.x-dev 7c72997
gedmo/doctrine-extensions   dev-master 1a86ba1
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master 2246a70
mopa/composer-bridge    v1.4.0
nelmio/api-doc-bundle   dev-master 874c875
sensio/framework-extra-bundle   2.3.x-dev f9e4c97
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle  dev-master c7c15ca
symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev e1ede46
twig/twig   1.x-dev 604e948
willdurand/negotiation  1.x-dev 4dd4643
```

Here is my compoer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*@stable",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "apy/datagrid-bundle": "2.1.15",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "v3.0.0-beta4",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "v3.2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "~1.0@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "ddeboer/data-import": "0.18.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.7.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "~2.8@dev",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "~1.3@dev",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "~1.0@dev"

    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3.33"
        }
    }
}
```